# Converting varbinary data back to image

Tags: python, ascii, varbinary

I have this varbinary string that I wanted to convert back to an image.
I tried using base64 encode but does not work. do you have any ideas or could you enlighten me the proper process. maybe there is a certain way to process this that I dont know of.

```
image = ""
with open("img_sample.png", "w") as img_bin:
    with open("string_binary.txt", "rb") as img_src:
        image = base64.b64decode(img_src.read())
        file = image
```

Comment: How did you get this `varbinary` string?

Comment: From the DB. no other info was given, except for ASCII. how would I approach this? is there a proper process for decoding?

Comment: Is the long string starting with `0xFF` the content of `string_binary.txt`?

Comment: yes. its too long if I add it directly to the code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the string is the content of the source file, it looks like a hexlified string prepended with `0x`.

So to get the binary data back, you just have to skip the initial 2 bytes and pass the remaining bytes to `binascii.a2b_hex`. You code could become:

```
...
image = binascii.a2b_hex(img_src.read()[2:])
...
```